# Aws lambda unable to read off a queue with encryption

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kms

So i have a queue that has encryption enabled with a kms. The kms policy works fine.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Enable User Permissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${account}:root"
      },
      "Action": "kms:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow sns to use key",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["sns.amazonaws.com", "lambda.amazonaws.com"],
        "AWS": "${role}"
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

However my lambda is unable to access the sqs queue, every time it tries to pull a message off it complains access denied by KMS. I have no permissions

I have set the policy for my lambda as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:sqs:xxx-1:xxxx:queue",
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sqs:DeleteMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:sqs:xxx-1:xxx:queue"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "KMSDecryption",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${kmsARN}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone have any idea how to configure my lambdas to access the queue. I have many lambdas that need to access to the queue. HOw can i give them access to the KMS to poll for messages, the lambda is wirtten in node.. do i have to do it in code?

Comment: Have you tried to use the AWS console, go to KMS, click on the key that the Queue is using and then add the role that your Lambda us using to that key?

Comment: so i found the issue, its related to the kmsARN, im using terraform aws_kms_alias, and trying to extract the arn, however its not populating with what i expect. in terraform im using the key alias "aws_kms_alias" to trya nd get key arn.. not key_alias arn

Comment: fixed it.. pointing to wrong arn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue was pointing to wrong arn. the above policies were correct.